# how to make the app click button automatically after user's click in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game. I want to create the one player part.

The user always starts with X.

When the user clicks on the button to write X, I want the device to write O on any button automatically to play with the user.

Here is my code but it doesn't work, when X wins the game, it will crash, but if O wins, the game works:

```
Button a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3,newGameBtn;
Button[] bArrary;
TextView thincrativTV;

// X = true ; O = false.
boolean turn = true;
int turn_count = 0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one_player);

    //set font path
    String fontpath = "fonts/ubuntub.ttf";
    //loading the font
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontpath);


    newGameBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_BNewGame);

    a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_A1);
    a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_A2);
    a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_A3);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_B1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_B2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_B3);

    c1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_C1);
    c2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_C2);
    c3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_C3);

    bArrary = new Button[]{a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3};

    for (Button b : bArrary){
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        //set custom font to all buttons
        b.setTypeface(tf);
    }

    newGameBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // we need to reset turn and turn_count and re enable all buttons
            turn = true;
            turn_count = 0;
            enableDisableAllButtons(true);
        }
    });

    // to make the copyrights work
    thincrativTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.onePlayer_TextView);
    if (thincrativTV !=null) {
        thincrativTV.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    buttonClicked(b);

    Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            randomClick();
        }
    },500);
    //randomClick();

}



public void randomClick(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    if (turn_count<9) {
        Button nextB = bArrary[rand.nextInt(bArrary.length)];
        while (!nextB.isClickable()) {
            nextB = bArrary[rand.nextInt(bArrary.length)];
        }
        buttonClicked(nextB);
    }
}



public void buttonClicked(Button b){

    // i just wanna change the text on the button to X/O.
    if (turn){
        // X's turn
        b.setText("X");
    }else {
        // O's turn
        b.setText("O");
    }

    turn_count++;

    // and change the turn
    b.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    b.setClickable(false);
    turn = !turn;

    checkForWinner();
}



private void checkForWinner(){

    boolean there_is_a_winner = false;

    // first we check the horizontals.
    if (a1.getText() == a2.getText() && a2.getText() == a3.getText() && !a1.isClickable()){
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    }else if (b1.getText() == b2.getText() && b2.getText() == b3.getText() && !b1.isClickable()){
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    }else if (c1.getText() == c2.getText() && c2.getText() == c3.getText() && !c1.isClickable()){
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    }

    // second we check the verticals.
    if (a1.getText() == b1.getText() && b1.getText() == c1.getText() && !a1.isClickable()){
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    }else if (a2.getText() == b2.getText() && b2.getText() == c2.getText() && !b2.isClickable()){
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    }else if (a3.getText() == b3.getText() && b3.getText() == c3.getText() && !c3.isClickable()){
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    }

    // finally we check the diagonal.
    if (a1.getText() == b2.getText() && b2.getText() == c3.getText() && !a1.isClickable()){
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    }else if (a3.getText() == b2.getText() && b2.getText() == c1.getText() && !b2.isClickable()){
        there_is_a_winner = true;
    }


    if (there_is_a_winner) {
        if (!turn){
            toast("X wins");
        }else {
            toast("O wins");
        }

        enableDisableAllButtons(false);
    } else if (turn_count == 9){
        // when all the buttons are clicked and disabled.
        toast("Oops!, Play Again");
    }
}



private void enableDisableAllButtons(boolean enable){

    // false to disable
    for (Button b : bArrary){
        b.setClickable(enable);

        //this is for color.
        if (enable){
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3c94d3"));
            //set the text back to original blank
            b.setText("");
        }else {
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
    }
}



private void toast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

*Note: X is user and O is the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see method `buttonClicked(Button b)` is only called when user clicks on any button. it is the user's turn, not be the machine.
so after you process user's turn, you can choose random button and call the buttonClicked() with it.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    buttonClicked(b);

    // now you choose random button nextB 
    // -> call buttonClicked(nextB);
    Random rand = new Random();
    // machine only can set "O" when the map has any button  (when turn_count < 9)
    if (turn_count < 9) {
        Button nextB = bArrary[rand.nextInt(bArrary.length)];
        while (!nextB.isClickable()) {
            nextB = bArrary[rand.nextInt(bArrary.length)];
        }
        buttonClicked(nextB);
    }
}
```

on method randomClicks(Button b) we will call b.setText("0").

```
public void randomClicks(Button b){
    b.setText("O");
}
```

I think it will work.

Comment: sorry but i don't know how can i choose random button nextB?!

Comment: i tried this but didn't work too:
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        buttonClicked(b);

        Random rand = new Random();
        Button nextB = bArrary[rand.nextInt(bArrary.length)];
        buttonClicked(nextB);
    }

Comment: bArrary contains buttons which are disable -> it can't work. 
now you can find the list on the rest of tic_tac_toe map (buttons which have not setClickable(false)). At this list, you can select a random button. 
I have edited my answer.

Comment: i really appreciate your help, but not working too.
i have edited my Code in My question, can you take a look again please?!
this new code working but sometimes the device cheated on me, meaning sometimes i click to write X then device remove X and replace it with O! and when X wins or O wins the 2 Toasts appears.

Comment: At this code: Button nextB = bArrary[rand.nextInt(bArrary.length)];
    buttonClicked(nextB);
nextB may be set disable at our previous turn, so if you call buttonClicked(nextB), the machine will cheat on the button of your turn. :v 
I have fixed the method onClick(View v) on my answer.

Comment: i have edited my Question and my Code again.. your new code working but when X wins the game was crashed but if O wins the game working perfect.
and i created method for randomClicks() and called it in onClick() and sets it in the delay.

Comment: when X wins, machine can not push O at any button, so we don't call myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            randomClick();
        }
    },500);.    I think calling randomClick() (when gameOver ) is cause of crash.

Comment: yes exactly, so what can i do to avoid this? is there a way to stop calling randomClick() when the X wins ?

Comment: you can use a flag. when gameOver, you mark the flag is true. before calling randomClick() you check this flag, if gameOver -> we don't call randomClick().

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand how can i make it :s

Comment: I have edited your post. the flag is isGameOver (boolean). When start game we set it to false, when finish we set it to true. Before calling randomClick() we check this flag.

Comment: Yes finally, it's works now :), i'm sorry i didn't understand what is the "flag" to use it.
Thank you for your time and your help i really appreciate that.